# Deploying Qt dll file - cannot find windows plugin although platforms/qwindows.dll exists and so libEGL and libGLES

Tags: c++, qt, dll, plugins, keil

I built my app as normal exe and run windeployqt on it. I got long list of files in folder with exe.

```
files:
./
D3Dcompiler_47.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Svg.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
WLedPlugin.exe
accessible
files.txt
iconengines
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
imageformats
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
platforms
qt_cs.qm
qt_de.qm
qt_fi.qm
qt_hu.qm
qt_it.qm
qt_ja.qm
qt_ru.qm
qt_sk.qm
qt_uk.qm

./accessible:
qtaccessiblewidgets.dll

./iconengines:
qsvgicon.dll

./imageformats:
qdds.dll
qgif.dll
qicns.dll
qico.dll
qjp2.dll
qjpeg.dll
qmng.dll
qsvg.dll
qtga.dll
qtiff.dll
qwbmp.dll
qwebp.dll

./platforms:
qwindows.dll
```

then I compiled app as dll and put it into folder with proper program. (I'm developing plugin for Keil IDE). DLL is seen well, but when part of code
with QApplication launches, then it can't find windows plugin.

So as you see qwindows.dll is in proper folder as libEGL and libGLESv2 are too and it still cannot see windows plugin.

I'am using msvc compiler x86 and Qt 5.3 version.

---

Some workaround found -> I simply threw msvc off and used mingw instead. It simply wroked.

Comment: You should read official documentation about deploying Qt applications: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html. You forgot to add `./platforms/qwindows.dll`

Comment: No I did not. qwindows.dll is in ./platforms folder as upper listing shows

Comment: Read this too: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html. I don't provide an answer, because there are a lot of ways, how to deploy :). For example, we are creating `qt.conf` file with cmake, as a build step. We have 4 differend configs, for debuggin and deploying on win + os x.

Comment: any heelp is appreciated. If I suceed I'll post solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i guess now i know a bit more what was the problem about.

I had folder with Keil application and folder with my dll plugin.
Windows check for called dll's dependencies in application's that called
dll directory in first, not in dll directory. Dll directory is in lower position.

Of course sooner or later windows should finally get to the dll's folder, but on some machines it didn't. Moving dependencies from DLL's directory to application's directory helped and is working well for the time being. Thanks all for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `qt.conf` near your .exe, or in resources to `:qt/etc/qt.conf`

```
[Paths]
Prefix=.
Plugins=.
```

Comment: @SaZ-> Does not work unfourtunatelly. I also tried to hardcode it with
qApp->addLibraryPath() with argument QDir::currentDirectory() and
qApp->applicationDirPath and still nothing.

I don't know if this really matters, but QApplication is in separate thread (of course it is the only QApplication in whole application). and I also cheated QApplication with argc and argv values.

I also don't know if this matters, but  I am not deploying *.exe but *.dll file

Comment: Can you create a sample? .dll with QApplication + modules + qt.conf. I try to look.

Comment: What do you mean by create a sample? Do you want source code or binaries? Sorry I just don't understand :) Thank you for your will of help :)

Comment: sory it took me so long. https://github.com/DawidPi/MKD51-Simulator here is the code, dependencies are in release, and qt.conf is : 
[Paths]
Prefix=.
Plugins=.

Now it's more like it works on my machine, but others not. It's like that after changing compilator to mingw 4.8.2. Error message is the same as I had with msvc compiler. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: QApplication is in file Controller->sources->guistart.cpp i forgot sorry