# Raising an error by running a program on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, owncloud

I've compiled ownCloud client for windows using steps mentioned [in doc secion of owncloud](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/1.7/building.html#windows-cross-compile). Now I want to run it under windows 7. But it gives me an error:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

I googled it but can't find the solution. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: do you have the Qt dll files in the executable folder?
Or try using the Qt command line tool to execute the .exe file.

Comment: You're probably missing the dlls mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14144077/3399252)

Comment: Yes, I copied Qt dll files in the folder. But it didn't solve the problem. I'm new in Qt. Where can I find Qt command line?

Comment: @Bowdzone , I copied those files in the folder, too. But nothing changed.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528595/deploying-qt-dll-file-cannot-find-windows-plugin-although-platfroms-qwindows-d/29538404#29538404

Comment: Thank @SaZ. As he said I had to create a folder called `platform` and copy `qwindows.dll` in it.

Comment: I propose you to use qt.conf for release builds, because you may have problems, if different versions of Qt will be installed on target machine.